# How to solve "You need permission to perform this action" error

Tags: windows, security, permissions

I need permission to move or copy or open or really do anything to this one .dll file which I NEED to move, it's located on a mounted .iso.

I've tried

- using administrator log in and it won't allow me to do anything with the file
- takeown in CMD
- looking at the folder properties that the file is contained in for security settings, and the folder only has "general","sharing","customize" tabs.
- every answer to this question i've seen, and none have worked

*Some extra info:* Yes, the security tab is visible in other folder properties

Comment: It would be helpful to know *how* is the .iso mounted - Daemon Tools? VCDControlTool? built-in Windows feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ISO-9660 filesystem is usually read-only, and the only way you can *modify* it (whether it is a CD or an `.iso` image) is to extract all files and rebuild, or to use a tool such as WinImage or MagicISO.

(The "Security" tab is not visible because ISO-9660 does not support it.)

If you cannot even *read* a file, it might be caused by

- another program keeping it open and locked; try Process Explorer or Unlocker;
- an antivirus gone mad;
- the filesystem being corrupted.

Unmount the image and open it in MagicISO or WinImage, then see if you can access the file.

Comment: I'm curious, how did you deduce that the filesystem is ISO-9660?

Comment: @Sathya: Quote from the question: "it's located on a mounted .iso." (It *may* be a UDF image of a DVD, yes, but the same restrictions apply: read-only and no Windows-compatible ACLs.)

Comment: d'oh - missed that line.

Comment: problem solved! I opened it in WinImage and it worked immediately, thank you very much!